# Accounting for overrepresentation of positives in binary classification test set for calculation of precision and recall

Tags: classification, binary-data, unbalanced-classes, precision-recall, prevalence

I have a binary classification task with highly imbalanced data, since the class to be detected (in the following referred to as the positives) is very rare.
For data limitation reasons my test set cannot have the representative prevalence (i.e. positives/total ratio) and at the same time contain enough positives for the statistical relevance I need in my results.
Therefore, there is an overrepresentation of positives in my test set by a factor of `f` compared to the representative prevalence.

Now I am wondering how to take this into account when calculating precision and recall.

My proposal is the following:

To account for the overrepresentation of positives, I multiply all contributions of positives (i.e. TP and FN) in the formulas by `1/f`.

Recall would not be affected, since it only depends on the positives and the modification would factor right out:

```
recall' = 1/f*TP / (1/f*TP + 1/f*FN) = TP / (TP + FN) = recall
```

For precision I would get:

```
precision' = 1/f*TP / (1/f*TP + FP) = TP / (TP + f*FP)
```

Does anyone know, whether this is a valid approach or, if not, can tell me the solution to my problem?

Many thanks in advance!